# MATLAB - Update Plot with Matrix

Tags: matlab, plot

I want to plot data, which is stored in an array. `A` contains three columns, each column represents a different data set. The following code works fine:

```
A = [0 0 0;
    0 1 0];
h = plot(A)
```

However, a new line is appended to `A` and the plot shall be updated. I read that you can update plots with `set` and `'XData'`:

```
A = [0 0 0;
    0 1 0;
    1 2 0];
set(h,'XData',A)
```

This throws me an error: *Error using **set**. 
Value must be a column or row vector*. Is there any way to refresh the data instead of a new plot? The following works just fine?

```
A = [0 0 0;
    0 1 0;
    1 2 0];
h = plot(A)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The initial code

```
A = [0 0 0;
    0 1 0];
h = plot(A)
```

generates three line objects, one for each column of `A` (check that `h` has size 3×1). So you need to update each of those lines in a loop. Also, you need to update both the `'XData'` and `'YData'` properties:

```
for k = 1:numel(h)
    set(h(k), 'XData', 1:size(A,1), 'YData', A(:,k))
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use linkdata (https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linkdata.html):

```
A = [
  0 0 0;
  0 1 0
];

plot(A);
linkdata on;

A = [
  0 0 0;
  0 1 0;
  1 2 0
];
```

Another approach deleting the plot and redrawing it immediately after:

```
h = plot(x,y);

% modify data...

delete(h);
h = plot(x,y);
```